# Is it possible to buy a physical copy of Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, live-cd

Don't want to waste money on buying windows 7, so the laptop is going to be ordered without an OS.
Is it possible to buy a physical copy (CD) of Ubuntu?

Comment: If you absolutely need a physical copy on CD and DVD but don't have access to CD/DVD burner (not even through a friend or colleague), I suggest you ask your local library or copy shop, because they can often burn CDs/DVDs for you. This may be a little cheaper than mail order.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a 12.04 LTS *(Not the latest version, but will [last until 2017](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases))* disk from Canonical - for laptops look at the 'Desktop' version:

http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976

But you could [Download the image](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) and burn it to a disk.

Answer (score 1):

Only the LTS version of Ubuntu is available as a physical disc (you can find why here: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/canonical-ditching-ubuntu-cdsdvds-for-non-lts ).

You can order it from here: http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17

Anyway, you can have any physical copy of any Ubuntu version on your own, by burning the ISO files. Download page: http://www.ubuntu.com/download

Answer (score 1):

there are three main Options -

1. Either download it from [here.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop)
2. Buy Ubuntu DVD from Canonical store from [here.](http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976)
3. Or contact your country loco team from [here.](http://loco.ubuntu.com/teams/).

Use google to know about your Ubuntu Country loco team.

Hope my answer is what you wanted to know.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy them on Ebay (from random people):

www.ebay.ca/itm/UBUNTU-13-10-32-64-BIT-LIVE-Install-DVD-Case-Sticker-Extras-New-Release-/111193376859?pt=US_Operating_Systems_Software&hash=item19e3a4485b

You can buy LTS discs from Canonical (the makers of Ubuntu):

http://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=976

You can buy from OSDisc.com (A company that sells linux installation media):

https://www.osdisc.com/products/linux/ubuntu?ad=google&gclid=CKv1gfCpnLsCFc9sfgodYmIA0A

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Canonical sells Ubuntu 12.04 32bit CDs at the [Canonical Store](http://shop.canonical.com/index.php?cPath=17).

Or you can order other Ubuntu releases, including 64bit, at [OSDisc.com](https://www.osdisc.com/products/linux/ubuntu).

Answer (score 1):

The most convenient thing to do (although you can buy directly a CD of Ubuntu) is to download your favorite distro (.iso) of Ubuntu and [burn](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu) it into a CD or a [pendrive](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu) (in this case be sure to apply a bootloader). In this case you pay less and you don't wait the delivery. If you want to give a contribution to Canonical for Ubuntu you can do it [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop) (after you choose the version you have the possibility to make a donation).

Be sure the version you choose is compatible with the hardware you are going to install on.